# Compare date time created for resources to local time in Azure

Tags: java, azure, sdk

I'm stuck when I compared between the date time when I created resource on Azure and the time this is local time for a week, using SDK of Java. I have read documents and doc of Microsoft but I can't figure out solution for this problem.

I really need to calculate the days between them. In this situation, I have tried to use the `until` method but that's failed. Do you have any suggestions?

This is my previous solution that I tried to modify but I think it has problem.

```
if(t.innerModel().timeCreated().getDayOfYear().comparedTo(localTime) <= 7
```

Thank you very much for all help or point in right way.

Comment: Fix the ALL UPPERCASE

Comment: You Question is unclear. You should specify what object you have in hand representing your date-time value. Also, Stack Overflow has *many* existing Questions & Answers on elapsed time. How have none of those addressed your issue?

Comment: Please don't yell at us! On the internet, all caps is equivalent to yelling.

Comment: It seems that you are on the way to writing a condition testing whether the time created is before or equal to the current time. Wouldn’t we expect that to be the case always?

Comment: What type does `timeCreated()` return? In case it’s an `OffsetDateTime`, it has methods `isBefore`, `isEqual` and `isAfter` for comparing it to another `OffsetDateTime`. The two are not required to have the same UTC offset.

Comment: @OleV.V. When argument of OffsetDateTime. It just returned values between created time date and real time. But I really need to how can I calculate the days between them, In this situation, I have tried to use until method but that's failed. Do you have any suggests?.

Comment: @OleV.V. I got it and fixed my problems. Thank you so much for you suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count days between two `OffsetDateTime`:

```
    long numberOfDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(createdOffsetDateTime, offsetDateTimeNow);
```

The two `OffsetDateTime` need not have the same UTC offset. The count works across different offsets too.

**Documentation links**

- [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html)
- [`between` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal))